# Creating an image of my hard drive

Tags: windows-7, backup, dd, img

I've been thinking of making an image of my laptop's hard drive for backup purposes.

What would be the best way of doing this? I know about dd but is there a more user-friendly way, perhaps a GUI front-end to dd?

Comment: You should use an incremental back-up solution like suggested by The Journeyman Geek or me, making an image will take a lot of time every back-up while the other way will add the differences to the back-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.clonezilla.org/

Answer (score 0):

if its windows 7, why not use the [built in backup tool?](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/backup-and-restore.aspx) it included a backup and full bare metal restore function i believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care to spend a bit of money, check out the impressive [Genie Timeline Professional](http://www.genie-soft.com/Business/genie_timeline_pro/overview.aspx).

This let's you go back in time, deleted a file 1 week ago? No problem, go back in time and recover it!

Answer (score 0):

if your OS is windows 7 you can use backup options of this OS  but if not you can use a program (acronis true image home 2010 or similar versions) ..... ((( win7 's back-up will copy every data but compression level is very low i guess but with the program you can decrease the size of your backup with %40 may be more but it depands of your data i guess)))